# Does "to spike" imply something plummets after skyrocketing?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I know that *to spike* means to rise quickly, and that's also what dictionaries told me. However, when talking about charts and graphs, the noun *spike* actually includes both the sharp rise as well as steep fall of a metric, hence forming a shape akin to a spike.

Therefore I wonder, does the more general usage of *to spike* in the sense of rising sharply also imply that the thing being described also quickly falls back down shortly after? Or does it both have and not have this implication, depending on context (aside graphs)?

Comment: Yes, the term derives from the shape of the graph resembling a spike (a stick with a pointed end)

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Then there's also spike as in dropping a Mickey Finn into someone's drink - to spike a drink; to drug it with the intention of rendering that person unconscious or incapacitated.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that _spike_ requires the thing described to **quickly** fall back down afterwards, but it definitely does imply that it falls back down. @PeterPoint And of course there's also the volleyball sense, which is almost the opposite of the sense asked about here, describing a steep _downward_ movement (usually followed by an upward movement if the ball hits the ground and bounces back)…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, you mean like a slam-dunk in basketball?

Comment: @PeterPoint A spike is basically the volleyball equivalent of a smash: hitting the ball hard in a steep downward direction to win the ball, usually done quite close to the net.

Comment: There is also [**power spike**](http://www.sweetwater.com/insync/power-spike-versus-power-surge/) in which the supply voltage rises steeply and drops back within milliseconds. The definition of a power spike includes the drop because, if it doesn't drop back rapidly, it's a surge.

Comment: @BoldBen I'd say it's the same thing, just a special case of this.

Comment: @busukxuan I agree, I just thought that it was a good example. By the way I wonder whether the naming of the volleyball example was influenced by the railroad spike which is driven downward into a wooden sleeper to hold the rail in place.

Comment: Jim is clearly correct about the use with graphs but what’s that “more general usage of to spike in the sense of rising sharply”? I’ve never heard that, nor anything like it.

What rises sharply but does not fall back quickly might have “peaked” but that would also need the value not to rise much further any time soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used in the sense of "a rapid upward change of a measure from a prior rate or value" the phrase "to spike" does not always entail a similarly rapid change back down.

Consider this example:

"The average cost for regular, unleaded gas is expected to spike to $2.49 per gallon this year, up from $2.13 in 2016. That significant uptick is in marked contrast to the steady price drops consumers have mostly seen over the past four years."
http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2017/01/03/gas-prices-expected-spike-2017/96111548/

Here "to spike" just means "significant uptick" with no anticipation of when the value will lower again.

That being said, "spikes" or "a spike" would tend to convey the sense of a short term deviation with a return to a lower value.  If I were to say: "The newspaper's website saw a spike in traffic when the mayor was arrested." the implication is clear that this is a short term increase.

Comment: Gas prices spiked at the start of both Iraq wars. They did not return to lower levels for years. A spike is pointy on both sides, but "to spike" only implies a sudden upward change.

Comment: That's what I said?

Comment: Pretty much. Just made it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to note that "spike" has several [definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spike):

- A pointed object, such as a large nail
- The metaphorical use of "pointed object", as with a "spike" in a graph
- To surreptitiously add drugs or alcohol to a drink
- To drive a volleyball or (American?) football downward sharply
- To "liven up" a party or meeting (often used as "spike up")
- To increase sharply

If gas prices "spike" that generally implies a sudden increase, as suggested by the last definition above.  While often there is eventually a downward trend sometime later, that is not implied/required by the word "spike".